# Transplant VScode setting to other

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

Please be aware that I'm unfamiliar with those tools.

I'm currently working with VScode and I have two settings with the same server, but the different users. At first, I set up 'the first user' and it works fine. However, for some reason, I had to create 'the second user' and use it (i.e. same server, same port but different Linux user). I tried to set the same setting with the first user but I failed.

1. Is there any solution to get the first one's setting and apply it to the other user?
2. When I see `Open Settings (JSON)`, both users share the exactly same settings, and also changes are shared across the users' JSON files. However, the first one still uses the formatter while the second one doesn't.
3. Can I get the name of the first user's formmater or linter?

## EDIT:

The setting file (Open Settings (JSON)) is on the local. Therefore, it must be shared. Then my question is how the remote environment works and how can I access the remote setting file? I checked `/home/.vscode/setting.json` file in both users and they are same.

Comment: Are the same extensions installed on both?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I set them up by using pip options in both users. Moreover, the extensions are same. The only extension I use for support python linting or formatting is Pylance, and it's installed in the both settings.